# Problemas Ao passar dados via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um formulário onde é validado pelo jqBootstrapValidation.js, e é enviado para outro arquivo, que é o arquivo abaixo:

```
// Contact Form Scripts

$(function() {

    $("#usuariosForm input,#usuariosForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var txtnome = $("input#txtnome").val();
            var ememail = $("input#ememail").val();
            var txtusuario = $("input#txtusuario").val();
            var pwdsenha = $("input#pwdsenha").val();
            var urltxt = $("input#urltxt").val();

            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }

            $('#submit').html("...Enviando");
            $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);

            $.ajax({
                url: urltxt,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    txtnome: txtnome,
                    ememail: ememail,
                    txtusuario: txtusuario,
                    pwdsenha: pwdsenha
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Registro realizado com sucesso</strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#usuariosForm').trigger("reset");
                    $('#submit').html("Enviar mensagem");
                    $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);

                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Desculpe " + firstName + ", ocorreu um erro. Por favor tente novamente!"));
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#usuariosForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Porém eu estou com problema, como tenho varios formularios queria usar sempre a mesma função. e passar a url para ele fazer o sql corretamente, ou seja, se eu passar a pagina cadastro_usuarios ele vai fazer cadastro de usuario. se ele passar update_usuario ele vai para a pagina de alteração do usuario. Tentei de um método de passar a url para o ajax da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" name="urltxt" id="urltxt" class="form-control text-center" value="?folder=usuarios/&file=ins_usuarios_usuarios&ext=php" data-validation-required-message="Por favor não mude os dados." required>
```

E no arquivo ele receberia numa variável, porém não esta funcionando. Como posso fazer isso? muito obrigado!
OBS.: A nomenclatura das minhas paginas são: ?folder=usuarios/&file=ins_usuarios_usuarios&ext=php

Depurei o código veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá algum erro no console?

Comment: @Aline não da erro nenhum :C

Comment: E pra que página tu tá enviando esse post? Consegue depurar esse js?

Comment: @Aline Trabalho com um carregamento dinamico, o link da pagina seria:
 ?folder=usuarios/&file=ins_usuarios_usuarios&ext=php

Comment: Humm... e se não tá dando erro no js, tá chegando na página? Tu consegue depurar?

Comment: @Aline pelo que vi não esta chegando na pagina.

Comment: @Aline , depurei o código e a variavel da url retorna undefined, coloque um print na pergunta

Comment: Sugiro que tu troque a url que está no value pra um: data-url. e remova a propriedade value. onde tu pega o valor, testa: .data("url"), ao inves de .val(). Pode testar?

Comment: Eu usaria o data-url no form certo? e onde pego o valor ficaria como    var urltxt = ?

Comment: <input type="text" name="urltxt" id="urltxt" class="form-control text-center" data-url="?folder=usuarios/&file=ins_usuarios_usuarios&ext=php" data-validation-required-message="Por favor não mude os dados." required> e no js: var urltxt = $("input#urltxt").data("url");

Comment: Aline deu certo, muitíssimo obrigado. tenho uma duvida, como no exemplo passado acima é um registro de usuário. não é muito inseguro eu passar a senha descriptografada pelo ajax? Tem algum jeito de eu criptografar no ajax e descriptografa quando chegar na pagina do PHP

Comment: Vou adicionar na resposta aí tu pode marcar, ok? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituir o value do inp:

```
<input type="text" name="urltxt" id="urltxt" class="form-control text-center" data-url="?folder=usuarios/&file=ins_usuarios_usuarios&ext=p‌​hp" data-validation-required-message="Por favor não mude os dados." required>
```

E no Js obter a nova propriedade:

```
var urltxt = $("input#urltxt").data("url");
```

No caso de segurança das informações:
Se é um cadastro de usuário, tu vai passr a senha que ele definiu e criptografar no servidor, a partir daí, ngm mais, além do usuário, saberá a senha. (Claro que isso dependerá do algoritmo de criptografia utilizado). 
No caso da edição do usuário, já virá criptografado, então é tranquilo.

Criptografar no js: Do que adianta? Se eu posso ver seu código js? (=

Comment: Realmente aline. Obrigado!